# Laravel Mailable not updating with code

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Mailable in Laravel 5.3
App\Mail\CustomerCreated. It was all working fine.

We needed to change the sender email so, I edited the from, and we needed to add 2 attachments to the 2 already there. I did it. No change in the mail.

I changed the blade, and it correctly sent the new data, but still wrong sender and wrong attachments.

I tried artisan commands:
php artisan clear-compiled
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear

Then I even commented out all the code in the build() of the mailable... and the mail still sent.

Answer (score 12):

Got the same problem. If you change `queue` for `send` it will work properly, but the actual fix is:

```
php artisan queue:restart
```

Comment: Great,Thank you. i tried config:clear and lots other stuff but this works

Comment: You, sir, have saved me a lot of time and headache today!

Answer (score 1):

Guess it wasn't mail after all...

I was sending via database queue, and as long as there was a similar row in queue it kept resending old one. When I restarted queue it all worked as normal.